# Getting data that was posted from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have a simple drop down box inside a form.  When a search button is clicked the value that was selected in the box is posted.  I need to get the value that is posted, back and put it in a variable so I can add that field to a DTO and then run a database search based on what the field was.  I want to use jquery to post and get the data back but unsure how to do this so Im just using plaing javascript for the post.

Javascript:

```
<form name="values" method="POST" action="MainPage.jsp">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="searchDropDown" id="searchDropDown">
        <option value="Volleyball">Volleyball</option>
        <option value="Basketball">Basketball</option>
        <option value="Hockey">Hockey</option>
        <option value="Soccer">Soccer</option>
      </select> 
      <input type="submit" value="Search Video">
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    SportsDTO dto = new SportsDTO();
    SportsDAO dao = new SportsDAO();
    var searchValue = $('#searchDropDown').val();
    dto.setSport(searchValue);
    dao.findBySport(dto.getSport);
});
</script>
```

I know the DAO and DTO work because I have a junit test written that passes

Just need to get the value back so I can run the database search and return the values into a table.

Comment: You need to bind a click handler to the submit button, use `.preventDefault()` to prevent normal form submission, and use AJAX to get the result of the search.

Comment: I am not sure if this applies to JSP as i never used it, but i have never seen an assignment like this in javascript: `SportsDTO dto = new SportsDTO();`. What is the first `SportsDTO` for?

Comment: Just a tip: your HTML (not javascript as you labeled it) is invalid. There should be a `<table>`.